# Using Content Enrichment without developing a custom WCF Web Service?

Tags: 2013, powershell, no-code-solution, content-enrichment

Reading the article [How to: Use the Content Enrichment web service callout for SharePoint Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163982.aspx) it looks like I need to develop my own WCF Web Service to use the Content Enrichment. The list of prerequisites clearly states I need:

> - Search in SharePoint 2013
> - Visual Studio 2010 or similar .NET Framework–compatible development tool
> - Administrator privileges on your SharePoint Server 2013 installation
> - A server on which you can host the service with IIS

[image]

I haven't found a way to use the **Content Enrichment** without custom code. Is it possible to use Content Enrichment just using PowerShell in a farm where I have Shell Access and administrator permissions on the SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I haven't found a way to use the Content Enrichment without custom code. Is it possible to use Content Enrichment just using PowerShell in a farm where I have Shell Access and administrator permissions on the SQL Server?"

And what exactly what CE be doing? The framework just lets you call out, but you still need to define what to do when the call out is made...

Comment: Content Enrichment would take the path of a crawled fileserver and add them as metadata to the crawled documents - before added to search index. And from your answer, I guess it's not possible without custom code?

Comment: Indeed, Content Enrichment merely allows the calling of web services (pretty powerful in itself), but that actual web service implementation, where it's hosted and what it does is completely up to you.